# Crossover frequency and resonant frequency

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, frequency-response

Physically speaking, what is the difference between crossover frequency and resonant frequency?

As far as I know, the resonant frequency is the frequency at which the system oscillates. And the crossover frequency is just a mathematical description on the bode graph

Comment: The crossover f is as you expect the point where a bandpass and band stop filter have equal effect to the transfer function. Often this applies the passive filters used to select bandwidth for speakers from bass,  Midrange and treble.

Comment: Resonant frequency doesn't necessarily produce sustained oscillations in a "system" and, if the "system" is (say) a Colpitts oscillator then the actual oscillation frequency will hardly ever coincide with a resonant peak in the filter circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about resonant frequency.  The "crossover" frequency 
depends on the topic.

As @John D pointed out in the comments, for controls, it's where the amplitude crosses 0dB.
In audio, it is more related to where gain lines intersect, such as where mid-range and tweeters "crossover" and their gains are equal.  See the image, where the blue and green cross, this is a crossover point in audio.  Note this is irrespective of the magnitude of the gain at this point, in fact it could be positive, or very negative.
[image]

The -3dB point, is where the output signal amplitude is half of the input amplitude.

Comment: Not necessarily.  In controls the crossover frequency can be where the magnitude crosses 0dB.  The -3dB point is more often called the corner frequency or the "knee".